# Can't run mongodb community 5.0 on arch linux

Tags: mongodb, archlinux, coredump

I can't run use mongodb on my arch linux.

package installed:  `mongodb-bin`

error when use `mongo`: `illegal hardware instruction (core dumped)  mongo`

My processor: `AMD Athlon(tm) II X2 270`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the
[release notes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/5.0/):

MongoDB 5.0 requires AMD Bulldozer or later.

How to check:

```
       cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep -i avx
```

(Advanced Vector Extention(avx) needed for 5.0)

Comment: More generally, MongoDB 5.0 requires advanced vector extentions.  See the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) for a list of processors known to support AVX.